# How do I use the nunit task's skip_test_fail parameter in Albacore?

Tags: rake, xunit.net, albacore

The [Albacore release notes](http://albacorebuild.net/2011/06/29/v0.2.6-ReleaseNotes.html) say the xunit task supports a `skip_test_fail` parameter that

> "prevents rake from aborting the build when an xunit test fails. This is useful in continuous integration scenarios, such as running with TeamCity."

No example was shown and my attempt to use it (below) was not successful. How is it supposed to work?

```
desc "XUnit Test Runner Example"
xunit :xunit do |xunit|
  xunit.command = "../xunit-1.8/xunit.console.clr4.exe"
  xunit.assembly = "Islambox.Web.Test/bin/Debug/Islambox.Web.Test.dll"
  xunit.skip_test_fail
end
```

Comment: The new method syntax is in the dev branch, there will be a release soon. You can do `xunit.skip_test_failures` now!

Comment: Najam, I have your answer and a new release of Albacore, come and get it! And accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the xunit task [source](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/blob/dev/lib/albacore/xunittestrunner.rb#L8) and see that the parameter *does exist*. It's a regular "property" that can be set to some value.

```
attr_accessor :html_output, :skip_test_fail
```

It's used in a postfix `if` condition, which will return false if the value of the property is `false` or `nil`. Any other value will return `true`.

```
if !result && (!@skip_test_fail || $?.exitstatus > 1)
```

So, just set it with any value! I recommend `true` so that it's more clear what's going on. I've updated [the wiki](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/wiki/XUnit-Task) with this information.

```
xunit.skip_test_fail = true
```

Comment: I filed an [Issue](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/issues/21) to get a method (like you invoked it originally) so that it's more intuitive.